# HeadlessモードでChromeDriverを起動したときにコンソールが表示されないようにする

Tags: python, google-chrome, windows-10, selenium

GUIのアプリを作っています。
その中でスクレイピングをするために
chromedriverとseleniumを使ってHeadlessモードでChromeを動かしているのですが
起動するとコンソールが開きchromedriverのログが表示されてしまいます
GUIなので表示されないようにしたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?

OS windows10
Python 3.6.3
Selenium 3.8
Chrome Canary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#での対策が以下のQ&A記事になっています。

[Hide/Silence ChromeDriver window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818436/hide-silence-chromedriver-window)
[Selenium+ChromeDriverで表示されてしまうコマンドプロンプトの画面を非表示で実行させたい](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/seleniumjp/PXFJTcdnx_0) 
[Selenium C# 4.0 release says you can hide the command prompt - how do you actually do it?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7898/selenium-c-4-0-release-says-you-can-hide-the-command-prompt-how-do-you-actual)

内容を抽出すると、以下になるでしょう。
この処理をPythonで出来るようにすれば良いと思われます。

1.いったんChromeDriverServiceオブジェクトを作成する
2.作成したChromeDriverServiceオブジェクトのHideCommandPromptWindowをtrueに設定する
3.ChromeOptionsオブジェクトを作成する
4.ChromeOptionsオブジェクトに（必要ならば他の引数と共に）引数"headless"を追加する
5.ChromeDriverServiceオブジェクトとChromeOptionsオブジェクトをパラメータにして
　ChromeDriverオブジェクトを作成する
6.作成したChromeDriverオブジェクトにて処理を行う

【追記】
調査を続けましたが、Pythonでは上記処理が難しいのかもしれません。
古いQ&A記事ですが、seleniumのソースコードを直接変更して、ChromeDriverを
起動する際に非表示にする力技のようなものが出ていました。

[hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

この質問そのものも、コンソールウインドウを見えない位置・サイズに
変更しておく、という技を使っているようですが、終了後にウインドウ
表示が復活するために質問しているようです。

---

**その後の状況**
質問者さん自身が英語版S.O.で質問したようで、そこで解決していました。
内容は@sa-yさん紹介の記事内容を汎用版(option追加)とすれば、目的特化型でしょうか。
[How I can hide chromedriver log on console through selenium p](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47755571/9014308)

他に、追記で紹介した記事に、追加の回答が付いていて、類似の処理が紹介されています。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883069/9014308

Answer (score 1):

以下のサイトにこのスクリプトにパッチを当てて、コンソール非表示で chromedriver を起動するようなオプション(hide_console)を追加する、という方法がありました。

- [Hide command prompt in Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654427/solved-hide-command-prompt-in-selenium-chromedriver)
- [selenium/webdriver/common/service.py](https://github.com/ITmasc/selenium/blob/05a5bb9e2dd603a0ee3ad05a94cc6063ff9c843b/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py)

こちらではうまく動くか確認しておりませんが、service.py を置き換えて試してみてはいかがでしょうか？